# How can I fix warning error on "export" from Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I tried to load my file from other props But when I want to execute my code I got an Error as "warn" in my terminal but I used export in my function as a code below.
My error is :

```
warn "export 'MenuButton' was not found in '../buttons/MenuButton'
```

My MenuButton code from Gatsby

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

export default function MenuButton(props) {
  const { item } = props
  return (
    <Link to={item.link}>
      <MenuItem title={item.title}>
        <img src={item.icon} alt={item.title} />
        {item.title}
      </MenuItem>
    </Link>
  )
}

const MenuItem = styled.div`
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 24px auto;
  gap: ${props => (props.title ? "10px" : "0px")};
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;

  :hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
      inset 0px 0px 0px 0.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  }
`
```

as you can see I used export but I got a warn and couldn't be executed it.

Comment: You can also `export default MenuButton` at the bottom of the page and just call the function `function MenuButton` see if it helps

Comment: How are you importing it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using relative imports but you need to allow webpack to understand them. You can [customize webpack's configuration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/add-custom-webpack-config/#absolute-imports) by:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, loaders, getConfig }) => {
  const config = getConfig();

  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    resolve: {
      modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules', './']
    }
  })
};
```

Something like this should do the trick.